# Specify the location of a maximized form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an MDI app, and I have recently added a new control to the MDI container, which covers the client area (the area where the children appear and function). The trouble is, when they try to maximise their forms, it appears behind the sidebar:

[image: Side panel overlapping child form]

Original form for comparison (to see the overlap)

[image: Original child form]

I know that I can restrict the total size of each form that gets maximised, using the `Form.MaximumSize` property, however I'm not sure how to set the x/y location of the form to sit next to the sidebar.

I could use the side panel as a marker, i.e. `x = sidepanel.Width` because that will never change, but I don't know how to apply that to a maximised form.

Alternatively, is it possible to give the sidebar the same behaviour as the menu bar? That is - the menu bar is not considered to be in the client area; so when a form is maximised it will not overlap the child form?

Comment: Your control on the MdiParent is "floating".  To properly work in an Mdi environment it must be **Docked** to one of the edges (the left edge in your case).  This will make it take up the entire left edge of the client area however...

Comment: @Idle_Mind ok, so I tried that, only trouble is that it takes up the entire side of the screen - that is to say that it even pushes the menu bars aside. Is there a way I can use this to simulate what I have in the above image (it sits below the menu bars)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some fiddling around, I found the main problem was that since I was adding the control dynamically, control of it was a bit difficult. So instead I did this:

- Added a panel (using the forms designer) to the MDI Parent
- Set the `Dock` property to "left"
- Added the custom control dynamically to the panel:

  ```
  SidePanel = new Menu_SidePanel();

  SidePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
  SidePanel.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left);

  panel1.Controls.Add(SidePanel);
  ```

Now, because the panel has been added to, and "docked" on the Parent form, the rest of the child forms, when maximised, use the Side Panel as another boundary.

[image]